# Tube with crooked presta valve won't inflate

Tags: presta, inflation

I tried to inflate my tire with the presta valve and it won't inflate. As you see in the image, the valve is a bit crooked. After couple of times pumping, it becomes more difficult to continue but tire won't inflate. The pump also has a little crack which lets the air out but it shouldn't be the problem because I inflated the other tire with schrader valve perfectly. Is there a trick that I can use or I need to change the tube?

[image]

Comment: You can try to bend it back. But what actually happens? Are you able to push the pump? Or does it leak?

Comment: Yes I can pump but air leaves from the pump crack and nothing goes into the tire. To add some info, when I push the valve (I assume it is called core) horizontally, it lets the air out.

Comment: Is your pump presta compatible? Some do both valves and others just Schrader

Comment: If it leaks and other Presta tube works - just change the tube. Note that a Schader tube might not fit the rim hole.

Comment: The pump has compatible heads with both types. The other tube is Schrader not presta.

Comment: If you can't bend the knobbie straight then replace the tube.

Comment: I tried to bend the knobbie and I think I didn't open up the valve all the way to the top before. It worked this time. thanks to all.